# taking snapshot during gameplay with opengl

Tags: c, opengl-es, blackberry-playbook

I am working on a game for blackberry playbook and in that game there is a requirement that during gameplay it should take snapshots in random positions and for this requirement I am using following open GL function

glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, params);

now I have two questions that

1. After execution this function sets NULL in params (GLUInt*), is this some sort of error if so how could I resolve this error.
2. Is this the right function to get snapshot, if no what other function should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You could be more lucky using [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glReadPixels.html). This function copies a part of the frame buffer into the client memory.

(I assume you're using OpenGL ES since you've mentioned a mobile device.)